# Is there a reduction when you say "is there "or "is this"?

Tags: pronunciation, parts-of-speech, speech, figures-of-speech, fast-speech-rules

I feel like  native english speakers drop the voiced th sound in fast speech when they say "is there.... ?" and "is this...?". Can you tell me if I'm right or wrong . Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your reply.

Comment: What do they do instead?

Comment: @IsabelArcher That's what I am trying to learn .I am pretty positive that I don't hear a th because when I watch in slow motion the tongue doesn't come out for the th. I think since it takes more time to link z and th ,they just drop the th to speak faster .

Comment: I don't honestly see how I utter either of the two phrases without pronouncing the "th".

Comment: Of course you don't hear it. It's not there. The fricative cluster /zð/ is difficult to pronounce and involves millisecond coordination between independent muscles in the tongue, jaw, and lips. It's reduced to /z/ whenever possible, which is pretty much all the time, in US English.

Comment: @JohnLawler thank  you. I appreciate that a lot .

Comment: @John Lawler, I don't know what to do! I've just said "is there" 20 times very fast and I could have sworn that I said "th" 20 times. I know that you know what you're talking about, so I'm not challenging you -- just having fun. But I am interested to know what it is that I'm really saying when I do that. I know I'm not saying "izzzzzere". I'd be grateful if you could explain it to me. Thanks!

Comment: @IsabelArcher You could easily be pronouncing it. Nobody can make a definitive statement about what *everybody in the world* does. I'm sure some people don't pronounce the *th*; I'm also sure that some people do. I've had this kind of debate with somebody here before. I essentially said, "I know exactly how ***I*** pronounce it, even if nobody else does it that way." The person tried to tell me I was mistaken. But unless they were in the same room as me, listening to it, recording it, and playing it back, they couldn't really know that.

Comment: @Jason Bassford, I'm sure you're right. I've heard a whole lot of accents, but I don't recall an impression that someone was merging those two words. But it must happen since several others here have heard it, and I'm sure they're not mistaken. I am going to pay attention to that from now on. FYI - I know for a fact that I do say "siddown", and a lot of other people do too!

Comment: @IsabelArcher Yes, I'm sure I say "siddown" most of the time too. Unless, of course, I'm being careful to pronounce them separately, as I would be if I were upset, giving a command, and pausing between each word. As in pointing at a chair and saying *Sit! Down!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Six of one half dozen of the other: in other words, you're right but you're also wrong.

Not everyone assimilates these sounds. I don't personally, but have heard many people assimilate the two sounds: /ɪz ðɪs/ becomes /ɪz zɪs/ or /ɪ zɪs/.